# Entity Framework can not generate a expression tree when linq query has List object

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have code below. When I run it, I got the exception:

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code
>       Additional information: Unable to create a constant value of type 'MvcApplication1.Models.QuantityPerUnit'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."

It seems like thant I can not use `List` in 
`public static List<QuantityPerUnit> QuantityPerUnitItems = new List<QuantityPerUnit>`. It should be replace with IEnumerable, but if I use IEnumerable it shows compaire error:

> System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'Add

Code:

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Models
{
    public class ProductEditViewModel : Product
    {
        // For DropDownListFor need IEnumerable<SelectListItem>
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SupplierItems { get; set; }

        // For RadioButtonFor need below
        public Int32? CategorySelectedId { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Category> CategorieItems { get; set; }

        // For CheckBoxFor need below
        public string QuantityPerUnitSelectedId { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<QuantityPerUnit> QuantityPerUnitItems { get; set; }
    }

    public class QuantityPerUnit
    {
        public string QuantityPerUnitId { get; set; }
        public string Quantity { get; set; }

        public static List<QuantityPerUnit> QuantityPerUnitItems = new List<QuantityPerUnit>
        {
            new QuantityPerUnit { QuantityPerUnitId = "1", Quantity = "10" },
            new QuantityPerUnit { QuantityPerUnitId = "2", Quantity = "20" },
            new QuantityPerUnit { QuantityPerUnitId = "3", Quantity = "25" },
            new QuantityPerUnit { QuantityPerUnitId = "4", Quantity = "50" },
            new QuantityPerUnit { QuantityPerUnitId = "5", Quantity = "100" }
        };
    }
}


[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ProductEdit(Int32 ProductId)
{
    var northwind = new NorthwindEntities();

    var q = from p in northwind.Products
            where p.ProductID == ProductId
            select new ProductEditViewModel
            {
                ProductID = p.ProductID,
                ProductName = p.ProductName,
                UnitPrice = p.UnitPrice,
                Discontinued = p.Discontinued,

                SupplierItems = from sup in northwind.Suppliers
                                select new SelectListItem
                                    {
                                        Text = sup.CompanyName,
                                        Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)sup.SupplierID),
                                        Selected = sup.SupplierID == p.SupplierID
                                    },

                CategorySelectedId = p.CategoryID,
                CategorieItems = from cat in northwind.Categories select cat,

                QuantityPerUnitSelectedId = p.QuantityPerUnit,
                QuantityPerUnitItems = QuantityPerUnit.QuantityPerUnitItems
            };

    return View(q.SingleOrDefault());
}


<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.QuantityPerUnit)
    @foreach(var Quantity in MvcApplication1.Models.QuantityPerUnit.QuantityPerUnitItems)
    {
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.QuantityPerUnitSelectedId == Quantity.QuantityPerUnitId, Quantity.QuantityPerUnitId)
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to separate out the portion of your query that you want to be translated to SQL and performed by the database from the portion that you want done on the application side.

```
var q = (from p in northwind.Products
        where p.ProductID == ProductId
        select new ProductEditViewModel
        {
            ProductID = p.ProductID,
            ProductName = p.ProductName,
            UnitPrice = p.UnitPrice,
            Discontinued = p.Discontinued,

            SupplierItems = from sup in northwind.Suppliers
                            select new SelectListItem
                                {
                                    Text = sup.CompanyName,
                                    Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)sup.SupplierID),
                                    Selected = sup.SupplierID == p.SupplierID
                                },

            CategorySelectedId = p.CategoryID,
            CategorieItems = from cat in northwind.Categories select cat,

            QuantityPerUnitSelectedId = p.QuantityPerUnit,
            //remove this from here
            //QuantityPerUnitItems = QuantityPerUnit.QuantityPerUnitItems
        })
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Select(p => new ProductEditViewModel
        {
            p.ProductID,
            //all of the other properties 
            QuantityPerUnitItems = QuantityPerUnit.QuantityPerUnitItems,
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Matthew.

When you get items from database, you operating with type IQueryable(T).
This type are translated to SQL script.
This kind of LINQ is called - Linq to entities.

To perform your operation, you need to use Linq to Objects.

You need transform your query to IEnumerable(T) with the help of method AsEnumerable() and then add static data to your ViewModel.